# I am facing a error in codeigniter hmvc 3.1.3

Tags: codeigniter-hmvc

This is `MY_Controller` :

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->module('Template');
    }
}
```

This is `Home` Controller :

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function index()
    {
        $data['content_view'] = 'home/home_v';
        $this->template->sample_template($data);
    }

    function about()
    {
        $data['content_view'] = 'home/about_v';
        $this->template->sample_template($data);
    }
}
```

Then makes:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: CI::$template
Filename: MX/Controller.php
Line Number: 59
```

Comment: This is my Template View: <?php $this->load->view($content_view);?>

Answer (score 0):

Bug in https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads?tab=downloads. They are still solving. I am waiting to leave the new version of HMVC. For ci 3.1.3 is not compatible with HMVC.

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation, yes it is but, bug I fixing my problem searching forum. Anyone write the solution.